# How to get a numpad with Enter button and decimal in Ionic 3 / Angular 4 App

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to get a numpad to display in my ionic app the includes an enter button and a decimal point, so that the user can enter numbers and decimals and hit the enter button to submit.

I've tried ion-input as number but it seems to display a tab as opposed to enter. I also tried tel but it seems to do the same. I also haven't had any luck with using something such as pattern="[0-9.]*".

The regular text keyboard does what I want. I can switch to numbers then enter the value and hit the enter and it fires my event, submits, etc but I don't want the user to have access to a full keyboard.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I tested `<ion-input type="number"></ion-input>` on my Android phone running 5.1 (Lollipop) and pressing enter submitted just fine. What you're experiencing may only be for specific devices or versions. You could try adding `(keyup.enter)="doSomething()"` to the ion-input and see if that works.

Comment: I attached a picture using that exact code. The keyboard in the picture above is the button I'm clicking. It does not fire the keyup.enter code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

html

```
     <ion-input
            placeholder="insert your answer"
            type="number"
            name="input-name"
    (keypress)="doSomething($event.keyCode)"></ion-input>
```

ts

```
  doSomething(keyCode) {
    console.log(keyCode);
    if(keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('Enter Pressed');
    }
  }
```